# Xmonad and Gnome does not work properly on new install of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, 16.04, xmonad

I have ran xmonad and gnome-panel in all my used versions of ubuntu, but this time around I cannot get it to work properly at all.

I first run these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gekkio/xmonad
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-xmonad
```

Im able to see all the choices from the login screen.  The only ones that work are regular xmonad and Flashback (Metacity) besides the default ubuntu login.  Though when I choose Gnome & Xmonad, that will let me log in and use xmonad but without gnome-panel.  If I use the mod + shift + q it will exit xmonad and bring up the gonome-panel right away but without any xmonad then, none of the shortcuts work from then on out.  The other choices will log in but immediately logout and put you back on the login screen.

The last version I used was 15.04 and this worked fine on there.  I want to figure out either where I need to look to find the errors and resolve them.  Or understand what might have changed and fix that. Where do I look to see error logs?  The only error stuff I have looked at is inside .xmonad xmonad.errors (which is empty) and .xsession-errors which shows

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: indicator-application main process ended, respawning
upstart: indicator-application main process ended, respawning
upstart: indicator-application respawning too fast, stopped
```

Any help is appreciated.  If I need to post the other files let me know what I need to show to help.